# Las Imagenes y los textos se muestran a distintas alturas las tablas

Tags: html, python, django

Veran, algo falla al utilizar etiquetas table, pues los textos se me ponen a diversas alturas, lo que afecta incluso a imagenes.

Codigo html:

```
<table>
<tr>
{% for alfa in categoria %}
<td>
<img src="{% static alfa.foto %}"/>
<br>
<a href='http://127.0.0.1:8000/filtro_categoria/{{alfa.id}}'>{{alfa.nombre}}:<br/>{{alfa.descripcion}}</a>
</td>
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:cantidad %}
</tr><tr>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</tr>
</table>
```

Código CSS:

```
table{
    color: #CCCCCC;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como hago para que todas las imagenes se pongan a la misma altura?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sé que pones que has encontrado una solución que funcionará usando `valign`, pero te recomendaría que no la usaras y en su lugar hicieras lo mismo sólo con CSS.

El atributo **`valign` se considera obsoleto a partir de HTML5** ([fuente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody#attr-valign)); Esto quiere decir que aunque funcione ahora, no se garantiza que vaya a funcionar en el futuro (porque se le dejará de dar soporte). Sería **mejor usar `vertical-align` en el CSS**.

Así, el ejemplo que pones no cambiaría su HTML sino el CSS:

```
table td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edito: Al fin he encontrado la solución:

```
<td valign="top">
<img src="{% static alfa.foto %}"/>
<a href='http://127.0.0.1:8000/filtro_categoria/{{alfa.id}}'>{{alfa.nombre}}:<br>{{alfa.descripcion}}</a>
</td>
```

Lastima que al ser una variable interna de la etiqueta , **valign** no se puede pasar al css, obligando a ponerselo a cada etiqueta.
¿Alguien sabe si hay un modo alternativo con css? Probe algo llamado "vertical-align", pero fallo.

Comment: Podrías intentarlo Bootstrap, tiene un componente que podría ser justo lo que quieres.

Comment: Esta respuesta contiene dos imprecisiones: 1) el uso de `valign` no se recomienda; y 2) `valign` sí se puede pasar al CSS usando `vertical-align`.